# how to format an html hyperlink with a wildcard

Tags: html, hyperlink, wildcard

A webpage has a hyperlink to a file that is replaced and updated monthly.

The client wishes to put a month/year stamp at the end so that one can clearly see the last update in the name.
ex:  **myUpdatedFile_July2015.pdf**

Is there a method to use a wildcard to enable a hyperlink to find part of a filename such as  "**myUpdatedFile_**" so that webpage(s) do not need to be updated monthly as well?

```
<a href="myUpdatedFile_ * "> Link to Latest updated file </a>
```

Comment: In simple HTML there is no way. If you can upload ... I'm sure you can can put a variable there.

Comment: Are you asking if HTML can test every possible outcome of the wildcarded value `myUpdatedFile_ *` and find the 'latest' one? If so the answer is no.

Comment: No, you can either use a server-side script to find the last-updated/last-added file and generate the appropriate href, or you can use JavaScript to generate the appropriate link when it's viewed by a client (this assumes that the newest file is updated predictably).

Comment: the file is replaced monthly so that only one unique "prefix" in the file name would be there... 

but i see i need to approach this differently .. than something simple like a wildcard...

thank you all

Comment: Would you be interested in a JavaScript solution, or a server-side solution? If so [edit] the tags to your question to indicate which language(s) would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Since HTML is only a markup language it can't execute any commands nor has it  *wildcards*. You have to use a server side script (eg. PHP, ASP, node.js) or the simpler way is to use javascript to automatically write the current timestamp (month any year in this case) to the  tag's href attribute.
I'm not that much into js so I can't give you a code example but it is a very easy task.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, as HTML is not a dynamic language. Your simplest option here is to put the pdf in a folder, and link to the folder.

The more complicated option is, as @gergalyb indicates, to do something more complicated server-side.

I know this is not what you asked, but related: if you wanted to do link to an anchor on your page using a wildcard, you would need javascript.